# excel vba formula determining highest value based on text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hi currently i'm having a problem regarding the displaying of the most significant text among 4 rows in one column . What I have here is remarks of clients which is excellent,good,fair and bad ..and i would like to display the word excellent on a cell if it is present in that column , otherwise if good is the highest value present then it should display it ,if fair then fair or and lastly if bad then display bad
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eg5h.png)

Comment: could you maybe show an example?

Comment: like: `{=CHOOSE(MAX(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH({"bad";"fair";"good";"excellent"},A:A,0)),ROW(1:4),0)),"bad","fair","good","excellent")}`???

Comment: hi i've already attached a n image of the file and result i would like to make

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this is not too late to answer your question. Try the following formula:

```
=INDEX({"Bad","Fair","Good","Excellent"},MATCH(1,(MATCH({"Bad","Fair","Good","Excellent"},B2:E2,0)),0))
```

See the image for reference:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's not a formula, but the main trouble, as I see, is not to grade four known values you listed above, but to exclude empty and unknown values. Moreover, when such happened, user must be informed about it and make the right decision...

```
'''''''
Private Sub sb_Test_fp_Grade3()
    Debug.Print fp_Grade3(Selection, 1, True)
End Sub

Public Function fp_Grade3(pRng As Range, _
                          Optional pUnkMod& = 0, _
                          Optional pEmpDen As Boolean = False) As String
' pUnkMod - Mode of UnKnown grades handling
' 0-Ignore; 1-Info only; 2-Deny
' pEmpDen - Deny or not empty values. If Deny, then empty treated as Unknown
'           according pUnkMod setting

Const S_BAD As String = "BAD"
Const S_FAI As String = "FAIR"
Const S_GOO As String = "GOOD"
Const S_EXC As String = "EXCELLENT"
Const S_UNK As String = "UNK" ' UNKNOWN

Dim rCell As Range
Dim lVal&, lMax&, lUnk&
Dim sGrades$(0 To 4), sRet$, sVal$

    sGrades(0) = S_UNK
    sGrades(1) = S_BAD
    sGrades(2) = S_FAI
    sGrades(3) = S_GOO
    sGrades(4) = S_EXC

    lMax = 0
    lUnk = 0
    sRet = vbNullString

    For Each rCell In pRng
        sVal = rCell.Value
        If (LenB(sVal) > 0 Or pEmpDen) Then
            Select Case UCase(rCell.Value)
                Case S_BAD: lVal = 1
                Case S_FAI: lVal = 2
                Case S_GOO: lVal = 3
                Case S_EXC: lVal = 4
                Case Else:  lVal = 0
            End Select

            Select Case (lVal > 0)
                Case True                   ' Known values
                    If (lVal > lMax) Then
                        lMax = lVal
                        If (lMax = 4) Then
                            If (pUnkMod = 0) Then Exit For
                        End If
                    End If

                Case False                  ' UnKnown values
                    Select Case pUnkMod
                        Case 0      ' ignore them
                            ' do nothing
                        Case 1      ' info about them
                            lUnk = lUnk + 1
                        Case Else   ' 2 & any others - stop
                            lMax = 0
                            Exit For
                    End Select

            End Select
        End If
    Next
    If (lUnk > 0) Then sRet = " & " & lUnk & "x" & S_UNK
    sRet = sGrades(lMax) & sRet
    fp_Grade3 = sRet
End Function
'''
```